# Get data to other ViewController with custom UIActivity

Tags: ios, uiactivity

I try to add custom icon to UIActivity, and i did it, but i can't set UIACtivity. I want hat when i click the icon open other ViewController and take text and image from UIActivity.
I have this code

```
- (UIViewController *)activityViewController
{
    ViewController *viewController = [[[ViewController alloc] init] autorelease];
    viewController.activity = self;
    viewController.modalTransitionStyle=UIModalTransitionStyleCoverVertical;

    return viewController;
}
```

but this don't work

```
- (void)performActivity


{
    ViewController *viewController = [[[ViewController alloc] init] autorelease];
    [viewController.textField1 setText:self.message];
    [viewController.imageView setImage:self.image];
    [self activityDidFinish:YES];
}
```